# How can I be sure that a warning app violation has been resolved?

Tags: facebook

I got an email from case++aazqzqnklgexao@support.facebook.com the other day. They told me that my is app is 'creating a negative experience' because it (according to them) does not comply with

> Platform Policy 7.2: Native iOS and Android apps that implement Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for Login

When I login to my FB developer account sure enough I see a message that looks like this.

[image: message on my fb developer account]

The thing is that my app does not have an IOS or an android login. Just a javascript login. I replied and told them this and they replied

> Thanks for working with me to fix your app...

But when I login to my FB developer account, that message is still there. How can I be sure that this issue has been resolved?

Comment: did you ever get an answer or were able to correct this?

Comment: to make this more confusing, you can only reply with the email mailbox to whom the initial email was sent, which in my case, is a shared group mailbox with no ability to send emails